# using bootstrap components in angular 2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

Angular 2 cli makes it possible to add bootstrap js components and use them in project components.

While there are other bootstrap libraries like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) built specifically for angular 2.

I was wondering what are the differences between two approach and is it ok to use bootstrap components in angular 2 by simply npm install bootstrap and include in app scripts in angular-cli.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an npm package for bootstrap basically adds in some extra input bindings to help you get stuff done.

from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4s0ac9/difference_between_ngbootstrap_vs_using_plain/?st=iw1xmyrc&sh=0b70a359),

> ng-bootstrap gives you `Angular` input bindings for all the parameters
>   you might need to tweak. If you're just doing the basics then there
>   isn't much difference. But as soon as you need to access a Bootstrap
>   property that isn't controlled by a CSS class, then with vanilla
>   Bootstrap you have to do very un-angularish $(dom-id) references in
>   your Javascript logic, whereas if you're using ng-bootstrap that action
>   is accomplished by tweaking a property that's bound to the
>   ng-bootstrap component.

Personally I use vanilla Bootstrap and include jquery. I have read before to avoid including jquery like this but it has not caused me any problems yet. It can make it hard to do some things though. I had a problem using tabs and expandable cards. even with `ng2` I had to create `booleans` to keep track if they were expanded or not.

There is nothing wrong with using it. It is probably better and more safe.

> Another pro of using ng version is its light weight because of:
>   * not using jquery
>
> - readiness to use es2015 modules and lazy loading
> - readiness for tree-shaking to minimize the size
> - being ready to use any bundling type you want
> - template precompiling

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I have created directives to instantiat the jquery+bootstrap components.

My Directives has the handling for confgiuration needed to initialise the components.